# Author Versus CreatedBy Versus AuthorOWSUser managed properties

Tags: search, administration, managed-property, crawled-property

I am building a content search web part inside my team site collection, and i want to show the user how created an issue tracking item inside my web part. but inside the content search web part i found three properties which is related to the created by field named:-

- Author
- createdBy
- AuthorOWSUser

as follow:-

[image]

now i am not sure what are the main differences between these 3 fields. now based on my test i came out with the following:-

- Auothor will show the creator and any user/s who modify the item also.
- CreatedBy will always return empty results inside the content search web part
- AuthorOWSUSer will show the user who created the item. --This is the one i am searching about---

But now i am not sure why the CreatedBy will return empty results inside the content search web part !! although it suppose to be the one i should use.

Regards